# Thread objects not freed from memory

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, memory

I wrote a continuous script that collects some data from the internet every few seconds, keeps it in memory for a while, periodically stores it all to db and then deletes it. To keep everything running smoothly I use threads to collect the data from several sources at the same time. To minimize db operations and to avoid conflict with other db processes, I only write every now and then.

The memory from the deleted variables is never returned and eventually becomes so large the script crashes (shown by tracemalloc and pympler). I guess I'm handling the data coming out of the threads wrong but I don't know how I could do it differently. Minimal example below.

Addition: I don't think I can use a queue because in reality multiple functions are threaded from this point, modifying different local variables.

```
import threading
import time
import tracemalloc
import pympler.muppy, pympler.summary
import gc

tracemalloc.start()

def a():
    # collect data
    collection.update({int(time.time()): list(range(1,1000))})
    return

collection = {}
threads = []
start = time.time()
cycle = 0

while time.time() < start + 60:
    cycle += 1
    t = threading.Thread(target = a)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    for t in threads:
        if t.is_alive() == False:
            t.join()

    # periodically delete data
    delete = []
    for key, val in collection.items():
        if key < time.time() - 10:
            delete.append(key)
    for delet in delete:
        print('DELETING:', delet)
        del collection[delet]

    gc.collect()
    print('CYCLE:', cycle, 'THREADS:', threading.active_count(), 'COLLECTION:', len(collection))
    print(tracemalloc.get_traced_memory())
    all_objects = pympler.muppy.get_objects()
    sum1 = pympler.summary.summarize(all_objects)
    pympler.summary.print_(sum1)
```

Comment: I don't think this is related to threading, because AFAIK a thread does not have its own memory region but both parent and child thread share the same memory. Did you try it without threads?

Comment: it is indeed not a threading issue per se, but just the side effect of using that dict as a "return value" thingie. Indeed, queues would be the correct way to go, so maybe you take a look at queues again?

Comment: I *tried* to fix the memory leak in your script and brought it down to [this script](https://gist.github.com/philippkeller/42bc9bd7c055788fff078fb91e009093) that is without threading and without the dict, and it still shows the same increase in memory while deleting the data. I give up, maybe someone else wants to continue there